# Python Numpy polyfit row index as x?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to calculate a best fit single order regression, because I would like to get the slop.

How can I use the data row index as x?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

data1 = [("Temp"),
        (101),
        (103),
        (104),
        (101)
         ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
shape = df1.shape
N = (shape[0])


print(df1)
print(N)

T1 = pd.concat([df1.iloc[1: , 0]], axis=1)
print(T1)

T1V1 = np.polyfit(x, T1, 1)
print(T1V1)
```

I'm unsure if I'm even getting the sort of info I want (I'm after the slope). But this errors out, with the following...

Output:

```
      0
0  Temp
1   101
2   103
3   104
4   101
5
     0
1  101
2  103
3  104
4  101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getslope-tiny.py", line 24, in <module>
    T1V1 = np.polyfit(x, T1, 1)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: What's variable `x`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your dataframe. You should definitely preprocess your data first. For example, in this case, the 'Temp' in your `df1` are all `objects`, whereas we want them to be numeric (int or floats). Let's fix that first.

```
data1 = [("Temp"), (101), (103), (104), (101)]
data1 = [i for i in data1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({data1[0]: data1[1:]})
# reset index to use as x for fitting
df1 = df1.reset_index()
z = np.polyfit(df1['index'], df1['Temp'], 1)
# array([1.00e-01, 1.02e+02])
```

You can also visualise the fit as follows:

```
z = np.polyfit(df1['index'], df1['Temp'], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
xp = np.linspace(1, 4, 10)


plt.plot(x, y, label='Data')
plt.plot(xp, p(xp), label='Fit')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image: Linear fit]

As you can see, linear fit is probably not the best for your data.

Comment: That didn't format. Basically I have a dataframe, live data (sensors, but stocks work), and each time I create a frame, I want to do calculations on it. I keep having the issue of having a frame created (with live data) that starts with the first row being the header and not the label. Stuck there.